# Conditional division in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I'm trying to calculate the price of a products in R. Because not all products were sold some don't have an actual sales price. I would like to calculate the sales price and return a blank space for values without sales price.

I started with this function but it does not seem to work.

```
sale.price <- function(price) {
  if (CM.sample$Sales > 0) {
    return(CM.sample$Sales / CM.sample$Product.Quantity.Purchased)
  } else {
    return("")
  }
 }

 sale.price <- as.numeric(sapply(sale.price, price))
```

This is an example of my data.

```
Product   Sales   Order.Quantity  Price
P1         120         2
P2          45         1
P3                
P4          25         2
P5   
P6         180         3
```

Ideally I would like the end result to look like this.

```
 Product   Sales   Order.Quantity  Price
 P1         120         2           60
 P2          45         1           45
 P3                                 
 P4          25         2           12.5
 P5   
 P6         180         3           60
```

Comment: You've got several issues, but it will be much easier to show you how to fix them if you provide your data using `dput`. Paste into your question the output of `dput(CM.sample[1:6, ])`

Comment: Thank you for your reply @eipi10, I tried outputting with 'dput' but the output very large and not readable. The data.frame is quite large and some columns include large arrays contain strings of text, which is why it might not work?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
# Initialize with ""
CM.sample$Price <- ""
# Calculate for rows with quantites
CM.sample$Price[as.numeric(as.character(CM.sample$Sales)) > 0] <- CM.sample$Sales / CM.sample$Product.Quantity.Purchased
```

Comment: It looks like `Sales` has empty strings (`""` or maybe `" "`) where the values are missing. If so, then `Sales` is coded as a character or factor and division will result either in an error or all `NA` plus a warning, respectively.

Comment: Thanks @eipi10 for this relevant comment! Should work now

Comment: Thanks @HubertL, eipi10 is correct, empty strings contain  `""` which is where my issue lies as I'm unsure how to handle the error. I tried your code but I revived `NA` for fields that contain values for `Sales` and/or `Order.Quantity`, the empty strings remained empty which is good.